# iOSアプリ開発を依頼された時の納品の流れを教えてください。

Tags: ios, xcode

お世話になります。

人からアプリの開発を依頼され、依頼主にアプリを納品して
依頼者のアプリとしてリリースする場合、
Xcodeのteamアカウントを開発者のもので開発して、
依頼主のアカウントに「譲渡」してリリースするという形が一般的なのでしょうか？
あるいは、もっと正しい方法があるのでしょうか？

A:開発者（私）：アプリを開発後、TestFlightで依頼主に検品してもらって、
依頼主にアプリを納品する。

B:依頼主（お客さん）：完成アプリをリリース

という場合のリリースまでは
以下のような流れでよろしいのでしょうか？

①開発者がXcodeで開発者のTeamアカウント（下の画像）で開発

②開発者のiTunes Connect上でアプリを審査に提出

③審査通過後、TestFlightで依頼主にアプリの検品をしてもらう

④依頼主がDeveloper Programに登録し、アカウントを取得

⑤開発者が依頼主にアプリを譲渡して、依頼主のiTunes Connect上でアプリを公開する

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3):

唯一正しい方法というのがあるわけではありませんが、別のアカウントで提出したものを「譲渡する」という方法は一般的ではありません。

通常はソースコードを納品するというのがよくある形です。
クライアントがあまり詳しくなくてソースコードからリリースの作業ができない場合などは加えて、作業を代行するという形で、ビルドや申請を行います。
アカウントはクライアントが取得したものを借りるということが多いでしょう。
どこまで代行するかは場合によります。ビルドを除けば難しい部分は少ないので、ソースコード＋.ipaという形で納品して終わりというクライアントもあると思います。
または申請マニュアルを別途用意するなど。。。

いずれにしても納品するものはソースコードが基本で、iOSアプリの場合はさらにリリースするまでにいくつか必要な作業があるので、そこまで面倒を見るか（別料金でやるか）、クライアントに任せるかはケースバイケースですね。

「譲渡」という方法が最初に出てきたのはもしかしたらソースコードを渡したくないという意図があるのかもしれませんが、その場合でも譲渡の作業は不要で、バイナリの形で納品して申請はクライアント、アカウントを借りて申請まで代行するなどの方法で十分です。

Comment: 丁寧なご説明ありがとうございます！とても助かります！クラウドワークスの場合、クライアントに検品してもらわないと、料金をもらえないということなのですが、そこのところをどうするかというところです。クライアントは開発については一切分からないということなのです。  ソースコードを渡すのは何ら問題ないのですが、TestFlightというのを使うと、相手がアプリで簡単にテストできるようですね。

Comment: TestFlightで検品だけしてもらって、ソースコードを納品すればいいのかもしれないですね！